# ACID transaction with Kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a `List<SourceRecord>` of Kafka that I want to send, but I need that the send of all this record will be `ATOMIC` so if in the middle of the sending my Kafka producer `die`, and I already send the half of the list, I need to be able to revert what was already sent by the producer.

It is possible to accomplish this with `exactly once` strategy with `batch` process? I cannot find any documentation or example that covers this scenario.

Comment: The idempotent producer should handle this, yes. In latest kafka clients, it's enabled by default. Can you share your code? Are you trying to write a custom connector, or are you just using SourceRecord with producer api?

Comment: Thanks, is included in version 2.5.1 of Kafka Client by default?

Comment: By latest, I mean 2.8+. Otherwise, you'll need to create the transactions manually. Clients above 2.0 should work. I assume you've found snippets like the one showed here? https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with Spring using a local transaction:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafkatemplate-local-transactions

```java
boolean result = template.executeInTransaction(t -> {
    t.sendDefault("thing1", "thing2");
    t.sendDefault("cat", "hat");
    return true;
});
```

For a complete overview of transactions with Spring, see

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: Thanks but it have to be with Apache Kafka client

Comment: So, why did you tag it with spring-kafka?

Comment: My bad I added by mistake